# Apache POI version 4.1.2 build failing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I have imported all of the necessary files to run Apache POI version 4.1.2 but my build is failing in Android Studio. In the image below, you can see all of the necessary dependencies I have imported into Android Studio for the 4.1.2 version of Apache POI. If I remove all of these dependencies, the app builds fine. This is by far the most tedious API I have ever used. There is also little to no documentation for version 4.1.2 of Apache POI which seems to differ from earlier versions. I have included everything that the documentation says to include. I have also included an image of the errors that are occurring. Any help is appreciated![image]

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have updated the question to include the errors that I'm getting.

Comment: POI is written to be used on full Java platforms. Android omits a number of Java packages that POI relies on.